# How to migrate conversation history to metro Skype?

Tags: skype, windows-live-messenger, skype-metro

Is it possible to migrate conversation history from

1) old Skype

2) Messenger

to new Metro version of Skype?

Answer (score 0):

Found this on the Support sites:

https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12166/how-do-i-migrate-from-skype-for-windows-desktop-to-skype-for-windows-8

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon here, so mind expanding your answer a bit by rewriting he relevant portions in your own words?